# SDL not blitting my images to buffer

Tags: class, sdl, sdl-1.2

So I'm in the process of constructing a mini engine while I learn SDL, and I keep running into problems when blitting to the buffer and then flipping it. You, the screen remains black, no matter what I do. Could you guys help me out here?

I have two classes: the Graphics class, and the System Class that work together to blit images. Graphics class has a set out generic functions, and System utilises the functions. System has a Graphics object as one of it's varriables, off which all the graphics rendering takes place through. Where am I going wrong? The screen doesn't blit my image onto the buffer at all :(

//Graphics.h

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
#define GRAPHICS_H

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include <string>

class Graphics
{
    public:
        Graphics();
        void loadImages(SDL_Surface* image, std::string imageName);
        void drawImages(SDL_Surface* image, SDL_Rect crop, SDL_Rect Pos);
        SDL_Surface* ImgLoad(std::string filename);
        void flip();
        void cleanUp(SDL_Surface* image);

        SDL_Surface* background;
        SDL_Surface* buffer;

        friend class System;

    private:


        SDL_Rect backgrdCrop;
        SDL_Rect backgrdPos;
};

#endif // GRAPHICS_H
```

//Graphics.cpp

```
    #include "Graphics.h"
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_mixer.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include <string>

Graphics::Graphics()
{
    buffer = NULL;
    background = NULL;

    backgrdCrop = {0, 33, 32, 33};
}

void Graphics::loadImages(SDL_Surface* image, std::string imageName){
    image = ImgLoad(imageName);

    Uint32 colorkey = SDL_MapRGB(image->format, 0xFF, 0 , 0xFF);
    SDL_SetColorKey(image, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, colorkey);
}

void Graphics::drawImages(SDL_Surface* image, SDL_Rect crop, SDL_Rect Pos)
{
    SDL_BlitSurface(image, &crop, buffer, &Pos);
}

void Graphics::flip(){
    SDL_Flip(buffer);
}

void Graphics::cleanUp(SDL_Surface* image){
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
}

SDL_Surface* Graphics::ImgLoad(std::string filename)
{
    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* optImage = NULL;

    loadedImage = IMG_Load(filename.c_str());
    optImage = SDL_DisplayFormat(loadedImage);

    SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);

    return optImage;
}
```

//System.h

```
    #ifndef SYSTEM_H
#define SYSTEM_H
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "Graphics.h"
#include "Input.h"

class System
{
    public:
        System();
        void init(bool fullscreen, int width, int height);
        void input();
        void draw();
        bool isDone();
        void quit();
        void flip();
        Graphics g;

    private:
        bool done;

        Input inp;
        SDL_Surface* back;
};

#endif // SYSTEM_H
```

// system.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
#include "System.h"
#include "Graphics.h"
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "Input.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_mixer.h"

System::System()
{
    done = 0;
}

void System::init(bool fullscreen, int width, int height)
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    Mix_OpenAudio(22050, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 4096);

    if(fullscreen == 0){

        g.buffer = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_FULLSCREEN);

    } else {

        g.buffer = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    }

    g.loadImages(g.background, "swift.jpg");
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Picking Sticks", NULL);
}

void System::input()
{
    SDL_Rect basic = {0,0,0,0};

      inp.Update();
      g.backgrdPos = basic;

}

void System::draw()
{
      SDL_Rect basic = {0,0,0,0};
      SDL_Rect sprite = {0, 33, 32, 33};

      SDL_BlitSurface(g.background, &basic, g.buffer, &sprite );

}

void System::flip()
{
    g.flip();
}

bool System::isDone()
{
    return done;
}

void System::quit()
{
    g.cleanUp(g.background);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

//main.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>
#include "System.h"
#include "Graphics.h"
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_mixer.h"
#include "Input.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

SDL_Event event;

SDL_Surface* temp = NULL;

string name = "swift.jpg";


int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    System sys;
    sys.init(1, 640, 480);

    while(sys.isDone() == 0)
    {
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                sys.quit();

                return 0;

            }
        }

        sys.input();

        sys.draw();

        sys.flip();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a semantic error in `void System::draw()`.

When you declare  `SDL_Rect basic = {0,0,0,0};` you set its values to 0. If you check what the

```
int SDL_BlitSurface(SDL_Surface *src, SDL_Rect *srcrect, SDL_Surface *dst, SDL_Rect *dstrect);
```

function does you will notice the `basic` rect is used as `SDL_Rect *srcrect`. That will make the width and height of the `g.background` equal to `0`. And nothing will be drawn.

If you want to draw the entire `g.background`, put NULL as the `SDL_Rect *srcrect` parameter.